# php recursive insert string into string

Tags: php

I have a huge string in PHP. In it are many url strings such as:

```
background: #9dc9de url("@{base-url}/img/background.jpg") center top no-repeat;
```

What is the best method to go through the entire string, find any url strings and insert a hash code before the extension based on the current timestamp to get a result such as:

```
background: #9dc9de url("@{base-url}/img/background_013857308.jpg") center top no-repeat;
```

I'm currently trying to `explode` based on a few parameters but it's definitely not a clean idea.

Comment: Please define 'efficient' in this context. There are many solutions available, but we cannot make a subjective determination about which one will be the most suitable to your situation.

Comment: Efficient in terms of performance. The application will grow over time so the string being manipulated will grow.

Comment: Are you planning to parse the files by hand? If so, what editor will you use? If not, do you plan to parse the CSS via PHP? If so, what algorithm will you use to create the hashes? If not PHP, what? Your question does not contain enough information for us to provide specific answers tailored to your situation.

Comment: I have all of this figured out already. I'm minifying and combining css files on the fly. Before I output the string buffer I wanted to run through the string and insert a hash code based on the current timestamp. Codekit parses my LESS files for me but I don't know how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I simplified my request if it helps. Maybe I overcomplicated it before.

Comment: You could use regular expressions such as preg_replace (but it is difficult to learn).

Comment: What is the pattern of these `url strings` ? like .jpg, .png etc?

Comment: Well, they will always be enclosed within parenthesis and double-quotes just as the example line shows.

Comment: why are the image files getting a timestamp? are they actually changing, or do you just want to force a refresh? If so, better to append a version parameter instead of having to have multiple files on disk (e.g. background.jpg?v=013857308)

Comment: these are going on a cdn so that's out. I plan to check all the files periodically via cron and remove old files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with `preg_match_all('/\("([^"]+)"\)/', $content, $matches);` which matches anything inside parentheses and double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should't use that approach in a production server, as you will call all files everytime instead of fetching them from cache. But it could be a good idea for a development server.

I would use:

```
$tm = time();
$css = str_ireplace( array('.jpg', '.gif', '.png'), array('.jpg?t='.$tm, '.gif?t='.$tm, '.png?t='.$tm), $css );
```

Comment: The whole reason behind my intent is for caching purposes so I'm with you there.